# Solution of the differential equation $\,f(x)f'(x)+f'(x) = g(x)$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, problem-solving

How do we solve a differential equation of the form $$f(x)f'(x)+f'(x) = g(x)?$$

The coefficient $f(x)$ of $f'(x)$ post a difficulty that integrating factors doesn't work.

Comment: Hint: $ff'+f'=(f+1)f'.$ This equation is separable.

Comment: It does not need an integrating factor in current form and is integrable already, try integrating both sides.

Answer (score 5):

$$
g(x)=f(x)f'(x)+f'(x)=\left(\frac{f^2(x)}{2}+f(x)\right)'
$$
and hence, if $G(x)=\int g(x)\,dx$, then
$$
\frac{f^2(x)}{2}+f(x)=G(x)+c
$$
and thus
$$
\big(f(x)+1\big)^2=f^2(x)+2f(x)+1=2G(x)+2c+1
$$
Thus
$$
f(x)=\pm\sqrt{2G(x)+\tilde c}-1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ff'+f'=(f+1)f'.$ This equation is separable.

Comment: I see you have the same answer comment, maybe you can add a bit more?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I considered adding more, but I want to avoid giving so much that it basically gives the answer to OP. I think this type of question works better when the answers are hints than just full solution methods being laid out.